# Why is debugger not running?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis-7

I have a solution which contains the following:

- Website Project (using local IIS 7
  server) with a Default.aspx page
- Console app (sends request to Default.aspx page in Website Project

When I place debug points in the Default.aspx page and run the console app, the debugger does not start. I know the code in there is executed because it returns the proper response.

Why is the debugger not working?

Comment: What project is setup as your startup project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the web project from within Visual Studio or attach the debugger to the running process before starting your console application. I'd recommend the former.

Then when you start the console application your break points should be hit.

Comment: I tried running the Default.aspx page and then running the console app with debug mode, but it doesn't go into the page. Is there something special I need to do in the Default.aspx page?

Comment: @chobo - Are you running two instances of Visual Studio?

Comment: @chobo - there's the problem then. The debugger can only be attached to one process at a time. Just fire up a 2nd instance of VS and you should be OK.

Comment: In the second instance of Visual Studio I ran the default.aspx page, and it completes the page load. Then I went to the other instance and ran the client. But it did not go in the break points